# Selenium. How to swich to correct frame

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use SwitchTo() method to switch to needed form, but I cannot do it.
I have a complicated page, like in the following example:

```
 <frameset>
    <frameset> </frameset>
    <frame name="mbframe">
        <frameset>
             <frame>
                 <frameset> </frameset>
                 <frame name = "box"> </frame>
                 <frame id="messages">
                         <frame name="box">
                         !!! I need to access this frame
                         </frame>
                 </frame>
              </frame>
         </frameset>
    </frame>
</frameset>
```

Please, advise.

Comment: does the frame exist on load or does it render on an event?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("mbframe")
      .switchTo().frame("box")
      .switchTo().frame("messages")
      .switchTo().frame("box");

//Do your operations here

//Come out of that frame - It will point to the top frame
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Thank you for response, but this doesn't help. I get an exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchFrameException : Unable to locate frame: mbframe

Comment: I tried to access frame by frame index. I tried 0 and 1 and I got the following error:
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchFrameException : Unable to locate frame: 1

Comment: I think your frame structure isn't what you think it is. Does the (X)HTML validate?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("frame").name("box"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
IWebElement _eleframe = driver.FindElement(By.Id("overlayIframe"));
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame(_eleframe);
```